# Complicated Excel Issue with Google API and Python

Tags: python, excel, google-drive-api

So I know how to download Excel files from Google Drive in .csv format. However, since .csv files do not support multiple sheets, I have developed a system in a for loop to add the '&grid=tab_number' to the file download url so that I can download each sheet as its own .csv file. The problem I have run into is finding out how many sheets are in the excel workbook on the Google Drive so I know how many times to set the for loop for.

Comment: Or, you could download them in Excel format and use [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) to read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just downloading with xlrd and using that. Thanks for the link Rob.